# How to use Trigger on Multiple table?

Tags: sql, logging, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

I have multiple tables EMP_001,EMP_002,EMP_003,EMP_004 and so on.. All the tables have common columns. Is there any way to make a common trigger for the tables.

I wanted to log the deleted value of all these tables in a separate table.

Note : All these tables are using a single procedure for the delete operation.

Comment: Fix the data model so your "emp"s are not split among multiple tables!

Comment: **No.** A trigger is **always** on exactly **one** table

Comment: Add the delete "log" code also in the deleting Stored Procedure

Comment: Follow the suggestion @Gordon offered: fix the data model. Basic rule: *If you store a piece of data in 2 places, 1 of them is wrong*.  You have at least 4.